# Capture image with front camera without opening the camera application in android

Tags: android

I want to capture & save an image & get the url of the image using the front camera of the android phone without opening the camera application.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: "I want X, help me" is not a good question for SO. Please do some research and try on your own. If you get stuck feel free to ask a specific question and include what you have found out, done and what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the steps here:
[How to take photos](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

You want the front camera, so to choose the camera you should call

```
myCamera.open(cameraNumber)
```

and cameraNumber is the number of the camera that you want to use. if you have two cameras, you can call it with 0 or 1. try both parameters to see which camera each parameter activates.

Comment: Didn't work..
Bit simple tutorial??