# how to capture image automatically in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capture image with front camera without opening the camera application in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682928/capture-image-with-front-camera-without-opening-the-camera-application-in-androi)

my problem is I can do capturing only by using Intent to launch the camera and click the button to capture image. Is it possible to do it automatically by not clicking a button or what codes can I add to do this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know if this is possible or not & according to me that is not a right practice to capture image without user's knowledge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class CameraView extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnClickListener{
        private static final String TAG = "CameraTest";
        Camera mCamera;
        boolean mPreviewRunning = false;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

            getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.cameraview);
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blankImage);

            if(CaptureCameraImage.isBlack)
                img.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
            else
                img.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);

            mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
            mSurfaceView.setOnClickListener(this);
            mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
            mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }


        Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (data != null){
                    //Intent mIntent = new Intent();
                    //mIntent.putExtra("image",imageData);

                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                    mPreviewRunning = false;
                    mCamera.release();

                     try{
                         BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                         Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,opts);
                         bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300, 300, false);
                         int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                         int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                         int newWidth = 300;
                         int newHeight = 300;

                         // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
                         float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
                         float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

                         // createa matrix for the manipulation
                         Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                         // resize the bit map
                         matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                         // rotate the Bitmap
                         matrix.postRotate(-90);
                         Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                                 width, height, matrix, true);
                         CaptureCameraImage.image.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);

                     }catch(Exception e){
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                    //StoreByteImage(mContext, imageData, 50,"ImageName");
                    //setResult(FOTO_MODE, mIntent);
                    setResult(585);
                    finish();
                }       
            }
        };

        protected void onResume(){
            Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
            super.onResume();
        }

        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        protected void onStop(){
            Log.e(TAG, "onStop");
            super.onStop();
        }

        @TargetApi(9)
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
            Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
            mCamera = Camera.open(CaptureCameraImage.cameraID);
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");

            // XXX stopPreview() will crash if preview is not running
            if (mPreviewRunning){
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }

            Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
            p.setPreviewSize(300, 300);

            if(CaptureCameraImage.cameraID == 0){
                String stringFlashMode = p.getFlashMode();
                if (stringFlashMode.equals("torch"))
                        p.setFlashMode("on"); // Light is set off, flash is set to normal 'on' mode
                else
                        p.setFlashMode("torch");
            }

            mCamera.setParameters(p);
            try{
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }catch (Exception e){
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mPreviewRunning = true;
            mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            Log.e(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
            //mCamera.stopPreview();
            //mPreviewRunning = false;
            //mCamera.release();
        }

        private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
        private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
        }

    }
```

You need to call this activity Also check below line of code 
      mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
It's called twice 
1) If you want user interaction to take picture you need to commit first occurrence
2) If you want no user interaction (It will take photo as soon as it start)
You can find whole project at

https://github.com/sandipmjadhav/CaptureImage

Thank You

Comment: it worked Sir..thank you so much! its a big help on my part

Comment: Sorry Sir I can't vote, cos my reputation is not enough(15 reputation is required to vote).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can take images automatically without pressing the capture button. Your Activity which you are going to capture the image should `extends Activity` and `implements PictureCallback, ShutterCallback`.

You have to use following method

```
videoPreview.getCamera().takePicture(this, null, this);
```

*videoPreview* is an instance of the class that I have created, which `extends SurfaceView` and implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback`

`Camera.open();` is also in *VideoPriview* class